# Durability guarantee of soft commits in solr 4.0?

Tags: solr

Will Solr 4.0 with transaction logs ensure that successful updates are **always durable**, even with soft-committed changes?

---

The wiki says:

> softCommit = "true" | "false" — default is false — perform a soft
>   commit - this will refresh the 'view' of the index in a more
>   performant manner, but **without "on-disk" guarantees**.

But the press release says:

> Update durability – A transaction log ensures that **even uncommitted
>   documents** are never lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it all depends on the fact that the transaction log is not enabled by default. If you only use soft commits there's no durability guarantee, but if you enable the transaction log all changes will be registered there, which is safer.
The transaction log gives also the support for realtime GET.

Comment: So I enable transaction logs (thanks for that fact!) and I get both durability and realtime get?

Comment: Yeah, I'd say so! But I'd do a hard commit too once in a while. Also, I don't know exactly how recovery would work, but it seems promising.

Comment: I think enabling transaction log does not ensures durability, only hard commit ensures durability.This is from solr wiki for your reference-A soft commit is much faster since it only makes index changes visible and does not fsync index files or write a new index descriptor. If the JVM crashes or there is a loss of power, changes that occurred after the last hard commit will be lost. Search collections that have near-real-time requirements (that want index changes to be quickly visible to searches) will want to soft commit often but hard commit less frequently.

Comment: I stand corrected then. What I meant is that the transaction log could be used for recovery purpose as well, not sure whether Solr used it that way or only for real time get. Thanks for clarifying.